SwiftUI using ForEach on generic Identifiable protocol causes LLDB RPC Server crash
In Xcode 16.0, I have created a protocol (which normally represents an enum) and am using that in another Identifiable protocol as the id. When I do use it in a ForEach loop, I get an error stating "The LLDB RPC server has crashed."
In the Playground I have this code:
protocol MyFieldCode: Hashable {
   var title: String { get }
}

protocol MyFieldsEntryViewModel<DynamicFieldCode>: Identifiable {
    associatedtype DynamicFieldCode: MyFieldCode
    var id: DynamicFieldCode { get }
    var someData: String { get }
}

struct ContentView<Code: MyFieldCode>: View {
    let fieldEntries: [any MyFieldsEntryViewModel<Code>] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(fieldEntries, id: \.id) { entry in
                        Text(entry.someData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Based off of the error I am getting, this seems to be causing an error within the compiler itself. Is there a way around this error?

The problem (or one of them) is that any MyFieldsEntryViewModel<Code> can't conform to Identifiable

How did you call ContentView?

This was done in the Playground so I never needed to call it. The compiler errored on the code I wrote.

The name of the second protocol implies it should be implemented by a view model so this begs the question why you want an array of view models for your view?

Well if you add code that calls it properly (in a project) then the compiler will not crash

This was sample code. The original code that revealed the error had the MyFieldsEntryViewModel within a class that was passed in. I simplified it to something I could run in the Playground to demonstrate the error and let me try and find a workaround.
And the compiler definitely crashed when it was in a project.

I got around this issue by not making the generic part be the id.
protocol MyFieldsEntryViewModel<DynamicFieldCode> {
    associatedtype DynamicFieldCode: MyFieldCode
    var id: UUID { get }
    var code: DynamicFieldCode { get }
    var someData: String { get }
}

If you have a consistent type as the id, then the compiler will not break.
